# How can I pass Object to SQL server stored procedure using java code?

Tags: java, sql-server

```
public class Student{
 protected String Name;
 Protected String Marks;
 public Student(String name, String marks){
  this.Name=name;
  this.Marks=marks;
 } 
 //getters and setters for above
}
```

From my other class I tried below

```
Student[] std=new Student[2];
std[0]=new Student("user1","80");
std[1]=new Student("user2","70");
String section = "A";

Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://....");
CallableStatement stmt= conn.prepareCall("{Call UserDatils(?,?,?)}");
stmt.setString(2, section);
//stmt.setArray(3, std);
stmt.setObject(3, std);
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql,Types.VARCHAR);
stmt.execute();
```

Here the issue is with below two lines.

```
    //stmt.setArray(3, std);
stmt.setObject(3, std);
```

When I run the above with setObject it is saying, "The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.

I am not able to set this value.

Please help me to pass above student info to stored procedure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I WILL try to use 
  std [0] instead of std.

Comment: Same issue, The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported

Answer (score 0):

In general if you need to values of one object to another object than you need getters from one object and setter from others.That means you need to know exactly what are the instance members of both objects.Basically you need to know the both the objects involved.
Similarly in the case above when you are passing a Student object in the setObject method JDBC does not know how to convert the Student object to sql object.
JDBC has a set of custom mappings defined for some of the java objects onto corresponding sql types.
Refer docs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html

Hence mapping from any java type to sql type is not possible directly.

Comment: I tried with arraylist, list, multidimensional array and objects also but no use. Can you give me the solution that how can I do it.

Comment: "getters from one object and setter from others" I didn't get this one.

Comment: In general , if you copy from one object to other , you need to call getXXX() method from one object and setXXX()  method on the other object.

Comment: You meant, In above code student method needs to be get and set from other class?